# Cannot start multiple processes with X11 in docker

Tags: docker, x11

I have following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN \
apt-get -qq update && \
apt-get -qq -y --no-install-recommends install gedit && \
apt-get -qq clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

and use the following script to start bash in a container with X11 support:

```
XAUTH=$(mktemp -t docker-XXXXXXXX)
trap "rm $XAUTH" EXIT
xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -

docker run --rm --init -it \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xauth \
    -v $XAUTH:/tmp/xauth:rw \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw \
    -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    [image] \
    /bin/bash
```

Inside the container I can start `gedit &` in the background. The first process launches and all is okay, however, on the second launch `gedit` crashes with:

```
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)'.
  (Details: serial 717 error_code 10 request_code 130 (MIT-SHM) minor_code 1)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Subsequent calls to `gedit &` are not affected; only the second call fails.

I have tried the above with `xeyes` and this program seems to be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and solved it with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1242399).

> You can set [the option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc) `--ipc=host` to enable the docker container to communicate with host processes and also accessing the shared memories.
> The command to launch graphical application will look as follows:
> `docker run --ipc=host -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:freemat`